# CSS content Slider debate

Tags: jquery, css, image, slider

Help me settle a debate. Is it possible to code a content slider without using `overflow:hidden;`?

```
Slider Specs
Slides slide out left side as new slide slides in from right
Slides are DIVs
```

Basically is it possible to do this:
https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi

```css
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/taj-mahal.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ibiza.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ankor-wat.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
</div>
```

Without using overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a fullscreen slider, with that approach, it is possible:

```
 div#slider {
 border:2px solid black;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px grey;    
 background:transparent;

 max-width: 1400px;
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 z-index:1000;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/wKxgpz

To be 100% sure if its possible like this, with moving the margin, I would have to test couple things out first.

Comment: It looks like it works, I just changed `overflow: hidden;` to `auto` (btw the CSS in your post above doesn't have that property like the CodePen demo did)

Comment: Yeah i know, i have removed the overflow entirely. :-)